# Determining whether a sentence contains a specific word

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I want to know how to refer to a word of a sentence in a label. For example, I have:

```
label1.text = "books pencil pen ruler";
```

I want to say: *"if label1.text contains the word "pen" then do something"*:

```
if (label1.text CONTAINS THE WORD "pen")
{
    // do something
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: +1 simply because there seem to be many misconceptions about how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Regex word boundaries:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(label1.text, @"\bpen\b"))
    // do something
```

Much more robust than checking IndexOf or Splitting.  E.g. a simple `IndexOf("pen")` would match `"open"`.  Trying to fix that by making it `IndexOf(" pen ")` wouldn't match `"pen other words"`.  Or if you `Split(' ')`, it will not match in `"This sentence ends in pen."`.  Regex's word boundaries match all of these as you'd expect.  You could split on more word boundary characters, but it's much easier to let the writers of the Regex class do the work for you, than to try to understand word boundaries yourself.

Comment: Well I agree with the fact that the IndexOf answers are wrong :-)  But it's not necessarily more robust than splitting on word boundary tokens (though certainly it is a shorter solution, so +1 for that :-).

Answer (score 2):

You could use string.Split() to separate that text into tokens, and Array.Contains to check if the word is in the list.

```
string sentence = "books pencil pen ruler";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
bool hasFox = words.Contains("pen");
```

If you want to allow for more delimiters than just space (e.g. Tab), you can add additional separators when using Split.  If you care about case sensitivity of the match, you can use the overload of Contains that takes an IEqualityComparer.

Comment: What about this "I have pen. its color is black."

Comment: As mentioned in the answer... if you want more word delimiters besides ' ', add them to Split e.g. Split(' ', '\t', '.', ',')...  I upvoted @Tim S. because his answer deals with this issue more compactly.

Answer (score 0):

if the pen word is expected between words and not in start or end of string.

```
if(label1.text.IndexOf(" pen ") != -1 )
{
//do something
}
```

**EDIT**

As a result of discuss I found the **Regex could be the better option** for it.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(label1.Text, @"\bpen\b"))
{
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Which also matches `open` :-)

Comment: Fails to match "Bla bla bla pen"

Comment: Yup it is okay :) in this case there won't be a "bla bla bla pen" so its all good. Thank you :)

Comment: If the input text is "Bla bla bla pen" how does IndexOf(" pen ") find the "pen"?  It will return -1.

Comment: In my case there wont be same words in the string. All the words will be different. So its okay

Comment: I don't think the OP literally always wanted to match on that input string (else he could certainly hard-code the answer).  Your answer fails if the text being searched for is the last word in a sentence.

Comment: And now with the latest edit, you again incorrectly match `open` with `|| label1.text.IndexOf("pen ")`

Comment: Yes, I need something else to make it generic

Comment: Something like splitting on word boundaries, which my answer and @Tim S. do correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
if(label1.text.contains(" pen ")) 
     {
         //do something 
     }
```

Simply add space befor and after `pen`.

Comment: Simply add space befor and after `pen`.

Comment: Now try to match "Bla bla bla pen".  That does not contain " pen ".

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "books pencil pen ruler";
string s2 = "pen";
if(s1.Contains(s2) && s2 != "")
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to say. Well, I was just trying to avoid using a string array. Guess its just up to the OP to choose based on the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
string data = label1.Text;
string word = "Pen";

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    if(data.Contains(word))
    {
         // do work here
    }
```

Comment: Did you read any of the other answers and comments to the other answers?  Your answer duplicates several existing answers, and is wrong for similar reasons.